# What did Nebula look like before she was a robot?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

In the Marvel Cinematic Universe, what did Nebula look like before she was a robot?

Comment: Probably the same, but less robot-y

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for here.  In the *MCU* we only have her appearances in the movies, none of which show her before Thanos made modifications to her.  Besides which, even modified she at worse qualifies as an android, not a robot.

Comment: https://screenrant.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Nebula-Meets-Captain-Marvel-in-Avengers-257.jpg

Comment: Like a time lord assistant

Comment: @Valorum I'd imagine she wasn't bald though

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe - There are many bald women and bald aliens; https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delenn#/media/File%3AB5_delenn.jpg

Answer (score 5):

In the MCU itself we don’t know for sure but presumably she just looked the same but without the cybernetic enhancements. As we can tell she has been enhanced over the years by Thanos, she explicitly mentions that herself.

> **Nebula:** You were all I had, but you were the one who needed to win! Thanos pulled my eye from my head and brain from my skull and my arm from my body because of you!
>
> <sub>*Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*</sub>

It’s worth noting that 2014 Nebula we see in *Avengers: Endgame* has less enhancements than the 2023 Nebula. We see this as past Nebula has to take parts off of 2023 Nebula to not get noticed.

In the MCU comic *Guardians of the Galaxy Prelude* Issue 1 we see Nebula get a new arm which shows what she looked like before. Again she appears to just look like she used to but extra enhanced.

[image: Nebula receives a new arm]

In the comics, and maybe the MCU, Nebula is a member of the Luphomoid species and she looks like herself just without the enhancements.

[image: Nebula as shown in The Infinity Gauntlet]

Comment: So, a member of the Luphomoid species...but no wolf-like features? Comics writers just choose strange names sometimes, I suppose.